# Error in creating Google Calendar "Reminder"

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I am using below code to create a reminder in Google calendar (using Google API ver 2 for c# ):

```
    EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();

    entry.Title.Text = "testing from .NET";
    entry.Content.Content = "testing from .NET";

    String recurData =
   "DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20071202T080000\r\n" +
   "DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20071202T090000\r\n" +
   "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20071230T160000Z;BYDAY=SU\r\n";

   Recurrence recurrence = new Recurrence();
   recurrence.Value = recurData;
   entry.Recurrence = recurrence;

   Reminder reminder = new Reminder();
   reminder.Minutes = 15;
   reminder.Method = Reminder.ReminderMethod.all;   
   entry.Reminders.Add(reminder);
```

Getting Error :  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the entry exist? If so, does Reminders exist? (I mean both not NULL)

Judging from the api [link](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html). You have to add the event to the calendar before setting reminders:

```
Uri postUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");
EventEntry createdEntry = (EventEntry) service.Insert(postUri, myEntry);
//and then add reminders
```

[see this](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#CreatingQuickAdd)

Note I haven't worked with the Google API so I can't garantee if it works or not. You should debug the application and see the value of EventEntry and Reminders

Comment: i am creating entry.But how to create Reminders?
I thought this (as specified in post ) is only way to create Reminders.

Comment: Well does the Reminders object of entry exist because you add a reminder object to it. Can you post some code how you create entry?

Comment: can't you just set a breakpoint on the line that throws the error and check entry or Reminders if it's set. Entry seems set because else you would have an error each time you used it. Maybe it's something else, see updated post

Answer (score 1):

```
CalendarEventEntry saveEntry = myService.insert(eventFeedUrl, entry);

saveEntry.getReminder().add(reminder);
```

*Reminder must add after you insert/update action

Comment: Please format your code appropriately, please click the [orange question mark](http://i.imgur.com/GjKAG.png) in the question or answer text box for an explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should complete the update of the "entry" object.
use **entry.Update()**
after setting the reminder object..
hope this helps..